# Is there a setting to always have the current section highlighted in summary section?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

[image: Summary View]

As soon as I remove mouse-hover, the highlighted section goes away. Is there a way to always show the visible section indicator on the code summary view that was added recently as a feature in VSCode (Version 1.10.1)? If there is any editor settings I can do to show this, can someone point me in that direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not in VSCode Version: 1.10.1.

An issue is open for that: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21784